# May a woman study Kabbalah?

Tags: women, torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah

Is is permissible according to Jewish law, tradition or custom for a woman to study the Kabbalah (given that she meets all other qualifications and requirements or those also imposed on men)?

Comment: kabbala is the ultimate Torah shebal peh since it is only handed down through Rebbi talmid even today unlike other oral Torah which is written down. Many hold that women should not learn oral Torah unless it pertains to them,so I would assume that kabbalah would certainty fit into that category.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44042/3 And related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/is-it-forbidden-for-a-woman-to-learn-gemara?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31190/are-there-any-female-kabbalists

Comment: Chabad holds that women may learn kabbalah. I'm not sure under what circumstances they allow it, and how far women are allowed to go in their studies. But the woman (Shimona Tzukernik) whom many consider the world's top female expert on kabbalah is Chabad.